# Prevent cache from getting out of sync when returned objects are updated

Tags: .net, vb.net, caching, reference

Im using vb.net
I got a web application that quite frequently uses a cache to hold data for faster access. This Is a MemoryCache where objects are retrieved by reference. It’s a quite large project where the the type of the objects inside of the cache are unknown. Many of the objects that exists within the cache are holding internal properties corresponding to information that exist inside of the database. My problem is that when I modify a object requested from the database (but is received from the cache) I change the values at the reference.

Here’s a scenario where this problem is explained:

1. I request a list of data, the cache is having it so it is returned from the cache by reference.
2. I make some changes in the received list (say I change the name of item 3), now before I post it to the database I need to compare it to the original list. No local copy exists so the data is once again requested from the database (but received from the cache)
3. I compare the data (from 1. And 2.) as the data are pointing to the SAME reference I fail to detect any difference (there is none).

When I made the second db call in point 3 I got data from the cache without knowing it, how can I account for this and be sure that the data that I’m receiving are always a mirror of that in the database?

is there any good way of detecting when data in the cache have been modified? (not deleted, just changed)

I have had a look at CacheEntryChangeMonitor but have so far only been able to detect when data is or is about to be deleted, NOT when internal variables are updated.

Another solution would be to create a checksum of the object at the time when it is inserted to the cache, as I don’t know the type of the object and don’t know what variables it holds (*different depending on type)* I don’t know how to do this in a good way.

(function is made like this: `Function placeInCache(Of T)(obj As CacheKeeper(Of T)) As T` in order to support all of our possible objects)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different concepts and questions here so I will try and address them:

1. If you are changing something that affects a cached object, you should ideally have an easy way to invalidate the data directly. For example, if you change the name of item 3, you should have an easy way of knowing which cache items get invalidated and flush them directly
2. It is possible to add a cache parameter to any "fetch" method that says, "get from database and bypass cache"
3. You have to be very careful with cache, you can end up adding complexity for no benefit if you are not careful. It might be easier to live with shorter cache times and data that is not up to date for a short period (stale data)
4. You can split up cached objects so that instead of caching the entire list, you cache individual objects and reconstruct the list from cached objects. This might make it easier to invalidate stale cache entries
5. If entries in a cache are really large and slow to recreate from database, you can use a number of staleness checks based on checksum/updated date etc. and call the cache through a mechanism that makes the easy check for date to compare to the cached item before returning or refreshing it.